# Excel - resetting sort order of a spreadsheet with 7000+ rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

My coworker accidentally sorted one of the columns & saved the wbook. This messed up the original sort order we had (the rows were sorted by the "recorded date" column, where we enter the date of when we get an account into the spreadsheet). Rows that have blank cells in this column were placed at the top, then sorted from oldest to newest at the bottom.

I've tried custom sort with 2 levels - 1st level sorts the column by no color, so cells with no value in that column would appear at the top, 2nd level sorts the column by oldest to newest date.
However, i still see some accounts with no cell value in the column appearing at the very bottom of the wsheet, oldest accounts appearing in the middle, and complete blank rows at the top. We did not start recording the date 6 years ago, but we started recording them from 3 years ago.

Preserving the sort order is especially important when we need to search the history of the account by its name - to make sure the accounts that were renewed appear in order from oldest at top to newest at bottom.

We did not have an index numbering column before, & i just created one now so in the future, if it ever ruins the order, i can just sort that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are asking  how to get in the recorded date column with no value on them at the top. Just sorting by the recorded date should do that. Don't worry about doing two sorts.

If that doesn't work add Auto Filter, Apply the filter to show only blanks, add a very old date all the blank cells.

Remove the filter, sort the column. This should get things in the order you want. (maybe add your index info at this point)

Filter on the fake recorded date and delete that value from those cells.

Turn Auto Filter off

I hope this helps.